# Labview Percentage slider

Tags: user-interface, slider, percentage, labview

I'm trying to make a Vi where I have a percentage slider. This slider goes from values 0-255 (it outputs bytes) and I want it to instead of values 0-255, I want to show percentages and if the percentage is below 10%, I want the slider to output zero. I'm relatively new to labview and Im not sure how to do this without variables.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on the slider and go to display format. You'll also want to look through the other tabs as they will help you with the range and limiting you want.

Hint: coercing the output is what you want to make <10 show up as 0